# how to change padding of last element of li in css

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add a green button to the last list element as shown in screenshot, but the problem is I want to reduce the size of the original margin padding so to make the box little smaller in what it is not, but unable to fix it, I tried with height: 0px; but no luck.

Let me know how can I adjust this, My Bootstap.css file - [css file](http://pastebin.com/aqdhdFnE)

Screenshot-

[image: screenshot]

My jade file -

```
.navbar.navbar-inverse.navbar-fixed-top
  .container
    .navbar-header
      a.navbar-brand(href='/') uplift
    .navbar-collapse.collapse
      ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
        li
          a(href='/challenge') Challenges
        li
          a(href='/pricing') Pricing
        li
          a(href='/pricing', data-toggle='dropdown') 
            | Content
            b.caret
          ul.dropdown-menu(role='menu')
            li
              a(href='/') Blog
            li
              a(href='/') Landing Page Library
          // ul
        //li
        li
          a(href='/') More
            b.caret
        li
          a(href='/', style="background:green;border-radius:15px;") Get Started >
    // /.nav-collapse
```

Comment: Put your CSS IN the question itself.

Comment: @Godisgood Its around 6K LOC ..so do I need to really paste it here ?

Comment: Do you mean current menu item?

Comment: Just put the neccasary parts.

Comment: @SleekGeek yes, I want to reduce the size of green border around the last li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is obtained from `padding 10px 15px;`.

So to **reduce the width** reduce 15px to a less px value.

To **reduce the height** reduce 10px to a less px value.